# SQL Date type with format

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datetime, format

I need this format for my data `'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt'`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bills] 
(
    [Ordernum]  INT       IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [BillDate]  DATETIME  NOT NULL,
    [ItemsID]   INT       NOT NULL,
    [ClientID]  INT       NOT NULL,
    [PrisNoB]   FLOAT(53) NOT NULL,
    [PrisWithB] FLOAT(53) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Ordernum] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FKClient] 
         FOREIGN KEY ([ClientID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Client] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FKItems] 
         FOREIGN KEY ([ItemsID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Items] ([Id])
);
```

So where can I define the date format `MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt`?

I tried to do it like this:

```
[BillDate] DATETIME ('MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt') NOT NULL,
```

but I get an error.

Comment: Not how it works in SQL.  Convert to a string when you fetch the data.  The database stores the value using an internal format.

Comment: @GordonLinoff its not nice to keep converting the date to string and from string to Date every time i need to use it

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, SQL stores date in its internal format, so all you can do is specify datatype, which would be `datetime`. **There's no possibility** to change format of the date, in which it will be stored (afer all, why do you think it matters for the computer what format it's in? It's just bunch of numbers contaning information about date...).

The best you can do, is to define `view`, which will use `format` function. See [FORMAT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Then use that `view` instead of table.

Another way is to write query, which will return date in desired format, again using `format` function.

One more option is, since you specified WPF tag, is to get data to a program and handle formatting in presentation layer, i.e. in you program. This is, IMO, the best option, because it keeps fine separation between data layer and presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is not a view but a computed column.  You can add a column which calculates the formatted value each time as:

```
alter table bill add billdate_formatted as (format(billdate, 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt'));
```

You can store this value once by making the column persisted:

```
alter table bill add billdate_formatted as (format(billdate, 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt')) persisted;
```

Both of these guarantee that `billdate_formatted` is always in synch with `billdate`.

I don't recommend `persisted`.  That is usually used when you want to use the computed column in an index (although there are other situations as well).